How to modify the chrome back button behavior and tab session history?
Context

I am creating a Google Chrome productivity extension that blocks users from accessing YouTube videos belonging to their specified video categories (ie entertainment, auto, etc.)

My approach so far is this:

In the background script use a chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener to detect whether user has navigated to a youtube video page.
Use the YouTube API to take the videoId from the url and determine what category the video is in.
If the video belongs to a blocked category, use chrome.tabs.update to send user to a chrome extension page that tells the user that video has been blocked with additional options and information.

The problem:

I want the browser's back button to work intuitively, sending the user back to the page where they originally clicked on the video. This is not the case with my current approach. Currently, the browser's back button sends the user back to the blocked youtube video page which just redirects them right back to the extension page, creating a loop. I am looking

What I have tried

Using chrome.history.deleteUrl to delete the url from history. This did not work as it did not update the tab-based session history.


Set location.href to the new URL in your content script instead. You'll need to add the name of the page to web_accessible_resources. See also How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?.
